# String splitting

Tags: java, string

I have a string in what is the best way to put the things in between $ inside a list in java?

```
String temp = $abc$and$xyz$;
```

how can i get all the variables within $ sign as a list in java
[abc, xyz]

i can do using stringtokenizer but want to avoid using it if possible.
thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is simple enough that `String.split` should work here, but in the more general case, one alternative for `StringTokenizer` is the much more powerful [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

```
    String text = "$abc$and$xyz$";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);

    while (sc.findInLine("\\$([^$]*)\\$") != null) {
        System.out.println(sc.match().group(1));
    } // abc, xyz
```

The pattern to find is:

```
\$([^$]*)\$
  \_____/     i.e. literal $, a sequence of anything but $ (captured in group 1)
     1                 and another literal $
```

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

`(…)` is used for [*grouping*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). `(pattern)` is a capturing group and creates a backreference.

The backslash preceding the `$` (outside of character class definition) is used to escape the `$`, which has a special meaning as the [end of line anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). That backslash is doubled in a `String` literal: `"\\"` is a `String` of length one containing a backslash).

This is not a typical usage of `Scanner` (usually the delimiter pattern is set, and tokens are extracted using `next`), but it does show how'd you use `findInLine` to find an arbitrary pattern (ignoring delimiters), and then using `match()` to access the [`MatchResult`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html), from which you can get individual [group captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

You can also use this [`Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in a [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) `find()` loop directly.

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$([^$]*)\\$").matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    } // abc, xyz
```

#### Related questions

- [Validating input using `java.util.Scanner`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner/3059367#3059367)
- [Scanner vs. StringTokenizer vs. String.Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split)

Comment: See example of a typical way to match `"quoted"` contents like `'this'` and `"o'my"` with regex ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561353/matching-quote-contents/3561377#3561377 ) - you can do this with `Matcher` or `Scanner` as well.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you could think about calling [`String.split(String regex)`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) ...

Comment: Its the recommended way to go ! StringTokenizer is there just for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one:`temp.split("\\$");`

Comment: the problem is the prefix and suffix is $ so i want the string between 1st $ and 2nd $

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. I think regex can handle your problem

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a regex myself, like Riduidel said.

This special case is, however, simple enough that you can just treat the String as a character sequence, and iterate over it char by char, and detect the `$` sign. And so grab the strings yourself.

On a side node, I would try to go for different demarkation characters, to make it more readable to *humans*. Use $ as start-of-sequence and something else as end-of-sequence for instance. Or something like I think the Bash shell uses: `${some_value}`. As said, the computer doesn't care but you debugging your string just might :)

As for an appropriate regex, something like `(\\$.*\\$)*` or so should do. Though I'm no expert on regexes (see http://www.regular-expressions.info for nice info on regexes).

Comment: Whether or not human-readable delimiters matter depends on whether humans will ever read these strings! If you're asking a user to type these in, then yes, it's a curious delimiter. If this is something used internally or passed between modules, then it doesn't matter if it's human-readable.

Comment: @Jay a developer is also human. If it is a template and it needs change it better be readable, just like other code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I'd ditto Khotyn as the easiest solution. I see you post on his answer that you don't want zero-length tokens at beginning and end.

That brings up the question: What happens if the string does not begin and end with $'s? Is that an error, or are they optional?

If it's an error, then just start with:

```
if (!text.startsWith("$") || !text.endsWith("$"))
  return "Missing $'s"; // or whatever you do on error
```

If that passes, fall into the split.

If the $'s are optional, I'd just strip them out before splitting. i.e.:

```
if (text.startsWith("$"))
  text=text.substring(1);
if (text.endsWith("$"))
  text=text.substring(0,text.length()-1);
```

Then do the split.

Sure, you could make more sophisticated regex's or use StringTokenizer or no doubt come up with dozens of other complicated solutions. But why bother? When there's a simple solution, use it.

PS There's also the question of what result you want to see if there are two $'s in a row, e.g. "$foo$$bar$". Should that give ["foo","bar"], or ["foo","","bar"] ? Khotyn's split will give the second result, with zero-length strings. If you want the first result, you should split("\$+").

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple split function then use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) which has `StringUtils.split`.  The java one uses a regex which can be overkill/confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple manner writing your own code.
Just use the following code and it will do the job for you

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyStringTokenizer {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List <String> result = getTokenizedStringsList("$abc$efg$hij$");

    for(String token : result)
    {
        System.out.println(token);
    }

}

private static List<String> getTokenizedStringsList(String string) {

    List <String> tokenList = new ArrayList <String> ();

    char [] in = string.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder myBuilder = null;
    int stringLength = in.length;
    int start = -1;
    int end = -1;
    {
        for(int i=0; i<stringLength;)
        {
            myBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while(i<stringLength && in[i] != '$')
                i++;
            i++;
            while((i)<stringLength && in[i] != '$')
            {

                myBuilder.append(in[i]);
                i++;
            }
            tokenList.add(myBuilder.toString());                
        }
    }
    return tokenList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String temp = $abc$and$xyz$;
String array[]=temp.split(Pattern.quote("$"));
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
list.add(array[i]);
}
```

Now the list has what you want.